# Angular Js: Getting data from URL via $routeParams & $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope

I have an issue trying to pass some data from my URL using $routeParams in a $scope in Angular Js. Here is my HTML partial:

```
 <h1>This is: {{project[currentCat].id}}</h1>  //works
 <h3>test: {{project[currentCat].examples[currentEx].id}}</h3> //doesn't
 <h2>Category: {{project[currentCat].id | capitalize}}</h2>
```

The h1 tag works as I have it set up in my Javascript as so:

```
categoryControllers.controller('DataController', ['$scope', '$http','$routeParams',      function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
$http.get('json/data.json').success(function(data) {
$scope.project = data;
$scope.currentCat = $routeParams.cat; //works
$scope.currentEx = $routeParams.ex; //works but unable to get data
```

And my app config:

```
.when('/:cat', {
  templateUrl: 'partials/details.html',  //works
  controller: 'DataController'
})
.when('/:cat/:ex', {
  templateUrl: 'partials/example.html',  //routes correctly but unable to get data
  controller: 'DataController'
```

})

And lastly my JSON structure:

```
{
"animation":{
    "id":"animation",
    "desc":"This is a description of animation",
    "images":{
        "src":"images/animation.jpg",
        "alt":"Animation image"
    },
    "examples":[
        {
            "id":"example1",
            "name":"animation project 1",
            "category":"animation",
        }
    ]
},
```

Basically I want to be able to pull all data associated with the example based on it's name in the URL but not sure how to formulate the part below.

```
<h3>test: {{project[currentCat.id].examples[currentEx].id}}</h3>
```

Edit: Here is the HTML from the previous partial containing the link:

```
<li ng-repeat="example in project[currentCat].examples">
  <a href="#/{{project[currentCat].id}}/{{example.id}}">
    <img ng-src="images/{{item.id}}.jpg" alt="Photo of {{example.name}}"></img>
    <div>
      <h2>{{example.name}}</h2>
      <h3>{{example.level}}</h3>
      <h3>{{example.desc}}</h3>
      <h3>{{item.Description}}</h3>
    </div>
  </a>
</li>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: in your h3 tag now currentCat became an object with an id property? i though it was a param

Comment: Oops...that was a typo on my part, I corrected it above.

Comment: can i see your a sample url?

Comment: Yes, just added it to my post. The anchor tag links from my categories.html partial to my examples html partial. end result currently looks like this: index.html#/animation/example1

Answer (score -1, accepted):

your link will try to reach #/animation/eample1 and you are trying to convert that to 
data[animation] which is valid and data['animation'].examples['example1'] which is not because examples is an array it needs to be accesed through numeric index if you want to use the id you need to convert your array to a hash